# The type or namespace name `Player' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, using

PLs, i am working on aproject in unity and visual studio and it keeps giving me error, look.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor.Build.Player;

public class Obsticle : MonoBehaviour {

    public int damage = 1;
    public float speed;

    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) {

            other.GetComponent<Player>().health -= damage;
            Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Player>().health);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52657729/edit) your question to include the error that you are receiving.

Comment: What language are you using? Could you add a couple of tags to your question to indicate this?

Comment: remove this line "using UnityEditor.Build.Player;", does nothing for that code

Comment: @comphonia it doesn't help it just keeps saying the type of namespace name 'player' could not be found

Comment: @AndresGraciano might be a different script then, there should be an error window i n VS that should show you exactly where the issue is, that and intellisense should help. If its during runtime, double click on the error in unity's console and it should show the exact script.

Answer (score 0):

first of all making your own player class causes conflicts. change the class
name, dont use character either. lol. i use Guy. the player tag is fine, and recomeended. also:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.Tag=="Player") {

            other.GetComponent<Guy>().health -= damage;
            Debug.Log(other.GetComponent<Guy>().health);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

this is one of my pickup class OnTrigger methods,

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {

            //destroy 'obsticle'
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `using UnityEditor.Build.Player;`   refers to the Play window, and actual game Player, not the player character. you may need to make your own class